# Do I need a transit visa from Zagreb to Beijing if I have a Croatian Reisdence permit

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, transit, pakistani-citizens

I am from Pakistan and have a Croatian temporary residence permit. I want to travel from Zagreb to Beijing via Lufthansa with a connection in Germany.

Do I need a transit visa in this case?

Answer (score 1):

As you're flying with Lufthansa, you will be transiting either at Frankfurt or Munich.

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=pk&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=hr&TR=de&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Nationals of Pakistan holding onward
>   tickets in transit through Cologne/Bonn (CGN),
>   **Frankfurt (FRA), Munich (MUC)**, Hamburg (HAM), Dusseldorf (DUS)
>   or Berlin Tegel (TXL) **AND**
>    holding a Residence Permit issued by Croatia.
>
> - A maximum transit time of 24 hours through Frankfurt (FRA)
>     or Munich (MUC).

So, you do **not** need a visa.